# How add ID element to the Add To Cart?

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add an ID to a line that contains a class with the specified name (I'm talking about Add to cart)Can you help?

Current result:

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-selection-needed">Add to cart</button>
```

Desired result:

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-selection-needed" id="newid">Add to cart</button>
```

I found how to do it with the google chrome console, but I don't know how to write the code for the functions.php:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("single_add_to_cart_button")[0].id = "newid"
```

I tried that but the filter seems wrong:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_attr', 'add_cart_button_custom_id');
function add_cart_button_custom_id($attr)
{
    $attr .= 'id="my_custom_id_123"';
    return $attr;
}
```

Comment: You could try to override the template yourself. From what I saw, there is no filter on the add to card buttons (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/621d6a73f199b2a6482d9294e2750c96848e070c/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php#L31). Other solution, if you can have it added dynamically, is to add it using JS, like the answer below pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
$('.wc-variation-selection-needed').attr('id', 'newid');
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/5gm23pob/6/)

Comment: Thank you Rajen, However it's doesn't work on my hand. Can I use a script who doesn't need an action (click on button) to run ?

Comment: In fact, I use a plugin that triggers to open a popup when you click on the selected ID (the add to cart button).

Comment: you should call this function on selected ID button.

Comment: I have zero knowledge of WordPress, but as far as JavaScript and jQuery is concern it should work.